# How to use properly ui-select in ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

I have an `ui-select` which is wrapped in `ng-repeat` directive. Since they share the same scope I have several problems:

- after selecting value in first select second select is already prefilled with what I typed in first.
- placeholder is hidden and shows only when select field is in focus.

Here is the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="repeat in repeats">
  <p>Selected: {{repeat.id.formatted_address}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="repeat.id"
             theme="bootstrap"
             ng-disabled="disabled"
             reset-search-input="false"
             style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an address...">{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"
                       refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)"
                       refresh-delay="0">
      <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

The question is what is the proper way to use several `ui-select` directives to prevent those issues?

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/44Lo2Naw7joPCrgL8XwG?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directive for the address lookup and move your lookup logic into the directive controller. Each directive instance will have its own controller instance and therefore its own instance of `$scope.addresses` (preventing the behaviour of pre-populating the second select as well as the first).

```
<div ng-repeat="repeat in repeats">
  <address-selector repeat="repeat"></address-selector>
</div>

app.directive('addressSelector', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      repeat: '='
    },
    template:
    '<p>Selected: {{repeat.id.formatted_address}}</p>' +
    '<ui-select ng-model="repeat.id"' +
    '    theme="bootstrap"' +
    '    ng-disabled="disabled"' +
    '    reset-search-input="false"' +
    '    style="width: 300px;">' +
    '<ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an address...">{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</ui-select-match>' +
    '<ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"' +
    '    refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)"' +
    '    refresh-delay="0">' +
    '  <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>' +
    '</ui-select-choices>' +
    '</ui-select>',
    controller: function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.refreshAddresses = function(address) {
        var params = {address: address, sensor: false};
        return $http.get(
          'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
          {params: params}
        ).then(function(response) {
          $scope.addresses = response.data.results
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

For the ui-select placeholder to appear, you should avoid initialising the model (`repeat.id`), or set it to `null`.

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.repeats=[{}, {}];
});
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1K26xBVSjuBNQRGhIQPI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this. Each object in the array will have its own `selected` item. To add new repeats you simply `$scope.repeats.push({})` and to delete repeats do `$scope.repeats.splice(index, 1);`. If you want to push `$scope.repeats` to an API, remember to use `angular.toJson($scope.repeats)` instead of `JSON.stringify($scope.repeats)`.

Of cause `selected` sub item is not needed if you only have that data. I had more items so this was useful for me

**file.js**

```
$scope.repeats=[{}, {}];
```

**file.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="repeat in repeats">
  <p>Selected: {{repeat.selected.formatted_address}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="repeat.selected">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an address...">
      {{$select.selected.formatted_address}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index">
      <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

Output data might look like this:

```
$scope.repeats == [
    {
        selected: {
            formatted_address: "98 Hubin Middle Rd"
        }
    },
    {
        selected: {
            formatted_address: "100 Rogwart Way"
        }
    }
];
```